# sending data via URL but not displayed

Tags: python

I have 3 scripts : htmlTemplate.py, info.py and hello_get.py

here their code :

**htmlTempate.py :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from string import Template

user = getpass.getuser()

info_html = """

<html>
<head>
<title>- Project -</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><center> welcome </center></h2><br/><br/><br/>
Application : ${code_name}
<br/><br/>
code: ${code_version}
<br/><br/>
path install :  ${install_path}
<br/><br/>
os : ${os}
<br/><br/>
unix user :  ${user_name}
<br/><br/>
<form name="sendData" method="get" action="/cgi/hello_get.py">
Nom : <input type="text" name="nom">  <br/><br/>

mail : <input type="text" name="mail" /> <br/><br/>

D&eacutepartement : <input type="text" name="departement" /> <br/><br/>

Projet : <input type="text" name="projet" /> <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="OK" />


</form>
</body>
</html>

"""

info_html = Template(info_html)
```

**info.py** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, platform, getpass, tempfile
import webbrowser
import htmlTemplate

#user = getpass.getuser()

def main( server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path):
  user = getpass.getuser()

  contenu = htmlTemplate.info_html.substitute(
            code_name = code_name,
            code_version = code_version,
            install_path = install_path,
            os = sys.platform,
            user_name = user)


  url = "info.html"
  f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='/tmp/info.html', mode='w', delete=False)
  f.write(contenu)
  f.close()

  webbrowser.open(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server_IP = sys.argv[1]
  code_name = sys.argv[2]
  code_version = sys.argv[3]
  install_path = sys.argv[4]
  main(server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path )
```

**hello_get.py :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cgi, cgitb, os, sys, socket, getpass, platform
import htmlTemplate, info

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 


#dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
#hostname = socket.gethostname()
machine = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]) 
#user = getpass.getuser()

name = form.getvalue('name')
mail  = form.getvalue('mail')
department = form.getvalue('department')  
project = form.getvalue('project')

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>User data</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2><center> Resume </center></h2><br/><br/><br/>"


print "Your data : "

print "install path is : ", install_path
print "<br/><br/>"

print "OS is :", os
print "<br/><br/>"

print "adress IP is : ", machine
print "<br/><br/>"

print 'Unix user is : ', user
print "<br/><br/>"

print " your name is : %s " % (nom)
print "<br/><br/>" 

print "your mail is : %s " % (mail)
print "<br/><br/>"

print "your department is : %s " % (departement)
print "<br/><br/>"

print "your project is : %s" % (projet)


print "</body>"

print "</html>"
```

code server :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

when I execute info.py like this :

```
./info.py server software version install_path
```

It opens my webbrowser and display data : OK.

Buit when I type on OK button, it opens a new web page ( normal ) url contains the data sent by the support of OK (get method) button like this :

```
file:///cgi/hello_get.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&projet=stab
```

but the webbrowser display :

```
Firefox can not find the file at / cgi / hello_get.py? Henry & name = & email = henry@gmail.com department = IT & project = stab.
```

error should not be famous but I watched my code.

Comment: It opens this in browser as local file. So all links are treated as links to local files - so it tries to open local file `/cgi/hello_get.py` as normal file, not as web url (or python script). I think you need web server.

Comment: Yes the file is in /cgi, I changed script and his code ( before I used another script with OK button and it worked ...)

Comment: Seems Firefox needs file with full name `/cgi/hello_get.py?Henry&name=&email=henry@gmail.com&department=IT&project=stab`

Comment: And because you don't use webserver Firefox will treat that file as pure text file or pure HTML file. Firefox can't run python code in that file.

Comment: yes you're right, buth python script are hmtl code , and with others script it works ...

Comment: Python scripts are **not** HTML code - Python scripts **generate** HTML code. `info.py` generate HTML code because it was executed in shell. `hello_get.py` is read directly by Firefox and it is not executed in shell.

Comment: ok but even calling a html file it does not work ( I tried with an html file ) and it doesn't work .... I've the same error which is returned by the webbrowser ...

Comment: Show error in question.

Comment: the url : file:///cgi/testHelloGet.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&projet=stab  , the error returned by th webbrowser is again : Firefox can not find the file at / cgi / testHelloGet.py? Henry & name = & email = henry@gmail.com department = IT & project = stab.

Comment: Do you have file with name `testHelloGet.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&proj‌​et=stab` ? For firefox `?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&proj‌​et=stab` are not arguments but part of filename. Only web server treats this as arguments.

Comment: testHelloGet.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&proj‌​et=stab it's parameters which are sent when I click on OK button ...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : Ideas ?

Comment: Create file with name `testHelloGet.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&proj‌​et=stab` or install web server (for example `Apache` + `mod_cgi`)

Comment: I can't create a file with this name because it's an URL, and URL change when the user put informations ...

Comment: And therefore you need web server.

Comment: I have already a python server.

Comment: What do you mean `Python Server` ? `web server` create with python or `web server` executing python scripts (like Apache + mod_cgi) ? if server is on local computer then you could use `http://localhost/hello_get.py` and then this script will call `http://localhost/testHelloGet.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&proj‌​et=stab`

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
 
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
 
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]
 
httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()                                                                                                                      I execute it in one terminal,in other terminal I execute : ./info.py  server software version install_path and it opens the webbrowser and display data ...... you know ?

Comment: Ok, you have (the simplest) web server. So use url `http://localhost/info.html` for `webbrowser()`.

Comment: Could you edit question and add server code ? Now I see you have port 8000 set in server code so you have to use `http://localhost:8000/info.html`

Comment: you mean, I have to open the webbrowser in this link like this webbrowser(url)? Where url = localhost/info.html That's it's a "thin"b client ... for info.

Comment: at the beggining, I used URL like this localhost:8000/cgi/file_name.py, but now thay it doesn't works.

Comment: Always use `http://` in url.

Comment: Try first `action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/hello_get.py"` in  `htmlTempate.py` and leave `url = "info.html"` in `info.py`

Comment: yes I know, but now I put url = info.html and that's ok it works, but teh second page when I type in OK button, the URL are the data but nothing are displayed in the web page ..

Comment: Is BaseHTTPServer runnning ? It should print some information about connected client. Maybe it show some error.

Comment: when I try : action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/hello_get.py" and leave url="info.html", I type on OK and the webbrower propose to me to download hello_get.py (my webbrowser is iceweasel = firefox for debian). And what you want to leave url="info.html" ?

Comment: In file `info.py` I see you create local file `info.html` and you open it as local file in `webbrowser()` so I think there is no need to add `http://localhost:8000` to `info.html`. Of course you can save `info.html` in folder `/cgi` and then you could use url `http://localhost:8000/cgi/info.html`. If you save it as `/cgi/index.html` then you could access this page with shorter url `http://localhost:8000/cgi/`

Comment: localhost.localdomain - - [03/Jul/2014 14:35:41] "GET /cgi/hello_get.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&projet=stab HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  File "/local00/home/H10575/stuc/serverTest/serverCGI/cgi/hello_get.py", line 41
    print "Le chemin d\'installation est : ", ${install_path}    #dir_path                                     ^
  , but I import htmlTemplate , so why this error ?, the error comes from $ but why ?

Comment: You have error in `hello_get.py`, not in `htmlTemplate` - you have ` ${install_path}`

Comment: yes the error comes from hello_get.py from ${} but why this error ? Because I import htmlTemplate in hello_get.py

Comment: You have `${install_path}` and `${os}` in `hello_get.py`

Comment: You use ${install_path} as variable name but not inside text.

Comment: I don't see `import htmlTemplate` in `hello_get.py` - I think you think about `info.py`

Comment: install_path is a variable which is declared in htmlTemplate

Comment: You have two problem - first: you use variable `install_path` in `hello_get.py` but you didn't declare it (or didn't import it from `info.py`), second: use `install_path`, not `$(install_path)`. `$(install_path)` can be use in formatted text.

Comment: I have edited the code and put import info and htmlTemplate in hello_get.py but I have this error again : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local00/home/H10575/stuc/serverTest/serverCGI/cgi/hello_get.py", line 41, in <module>
    print "Le chemin d\'installation est : ", install_path #dir_path
NameError: name 'install_path' is not defined
--> install_path is defined in info.py

Comment: Did you heard about `namespaces` ? If you do `import os` then you use `os.somefunction()`, if you don't want to use prefix/namespace `os.` then you use `from os import *`. The same is with `import info`. You don't need `htmlTemplate` in `hello_get.py`

Comment: yes, but when I type on ok button ( to open hello_get.py and display data), the webbrowser propose to download the hello_get file , and here the error : localhost.localdomain - - [03/Jul/2014 15:13:44] "GET /cgi/hello_get.py?nom=henry&mail=henry%40gmail.com&departement=IT&projet=stab HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Download file and see whether you get source code or HTML. Can you run script without `python`, I mean `script.py`, not `python script.py`. Did you set `executable` for script (`chmod +x script.py`) ?

Comment: The file when I download it, it's virgin , and of course I gave rights to files with chmod +x and I edited with chmod 755 ....

Comment: Well, I started `BaseHTTPServer` in folder `xxx` and files in `xxx/cgi` with `755` are executed and I get correct result in browser. I don't know what to say more.

Comment: data are displayed with hello_get.py ?

Comment: I see almost all data with hello_get.py - I did'n add `import info`. But if I have some error in script then I see error message printed by `BaseHTTPServer` in console.

Comment: that's very strange , what's your webbrowser ? I use iceweasel which is firefox for debian ... I don't think that is a problem ...

Comment: Firefox on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu/Debian)

Comment: I copy/paste all your code and I have to add `import getpass` in `htmlTemplate` to get results in browser. But I know it because there was error message in console with `BaseHTTPServer`

Comment: well, I had only done chmod + x on serverCGI.py not chmod 755 , now it works ..... thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: wait :) , your install_path and OS are displayed or no ?

Comment: You `import info` so every variable and function from that file has prefix/namespace `info.` - try `info.install_path`. See in `info.py` `OS` is `sys.platform` so you can use `sys.platform` in place of `os`

Comment: I made : from info import * , so , I made : print "Le chemin d\'installation est : ", install_path 
print "<br/><br/>"
print "Votre systeme d\'exploitation est ${install_path}:", os                                                                  but the consol told me : 
print "Le chemin d\'installation est : ", install_path 
NameError: name 'install_path' is not defined , but I import info and install path is defined in info ...

Comment: I look at code and I see bigger problem with `install_path`. When you `import info` then there is no `sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], etc` - they only exist when you run `./info.py server software version install_path`. You will have to save than values in new file when you run `./info.py server software version install_path` and then read/import that file in `hello_get.py` in place of `import info`

Comment: Could you show me an example ?

Comment: You could use JSON format - `import sys, json ; config_file = open("config.txt", "w") ; json.dump(sys.argv, config_file)`. I use `;` to seperate lines.

Comment: could you show me that as an answer and not as a comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save:

```
import sys, json 

config_file = open("config.txt", "w") 
json.dump(sys.argv, config_file)
```

Load:

```
 import json

 config_file = open("config.txt", "r") 
 my_argv = json.load(config_file) 

 print my_argv
```

---

**EDIT:**

**/cgi/info.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import platform
import getpass
import tempfile
import webbrowser
import string
import json 

def main( server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path, user_os, user_login):

    template = open('htmlTemplate.phtml').read()

    contenu = string.Template(template).substitute(
            code_name = code_name,
            code_version = code_version,
            install_path = install_path,
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login
        )

    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='/tmp/info.html.', mode='w', delete=False)
    f.write(contenu)
    f.close()

    webbrowser.open(f.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_IP = sys.argv[1]
    code_name = sys.argv[2]
    code_version = sys.argv[3]
    install_path = sys.argv[4]

    user_os = sys.platform
    sys.argv.append(user_os)

    user_login = getpass.getuser()  
    sys.argv.append(user_login)

    config_file = open("config.txt", "w") 
    json.dump(sys.argv, config_file)

    main(server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path, user_os, user_login)
```

**/cgi/htmlTemplate.phtml**

I have only html and variable names - so I called it `p(ython)html`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>- Project -</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2><center> welcome </center></h2>
<br/><br/><br/>

Application: ${code_name}<br/><br/>

code: ${code_version}<br/><br/>

path install: ${install_path}<br/><br/>

os: ${os}<br/><br/>

unix user: ${user_name}<br/><br/>

<form name="sendData" method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/hello_get.py">
    Nom: <input type="text" name="nom"><br/><br/>
    mail: <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/><br/>
    D&eacutepartement: <input type="text" name="department"/><br/><br/>
    Projet: <input type="text" name="project"/> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**/cgi/hello_get.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi
import cgitb
import os
import sys
import socket
import getpass
import platform

import json

config_file = open("cgi/config.txt", "r") 
my_argv = json.load(config_file) 

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

machine = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]) 

nom = form.getvalue('nom')
mail = form.getvalue('mail')
department = form.getvalue('department')  
project = form.getvalue('project')

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>User data</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2><center> Resume </center></h2><br/><br/><br/>"
print "Your data : "
print "install path is : ", my_argv[4]
print "<br/><br/>"
print "OS is :", my_argv[5]
print "<br/><br/>"
print "adress IP is : ", machine
print "<br/><br/>"
print 'Unix user is : ', my_argv[6]
print "<br/><br/>"
print "your name is :", nom
print "<br/><br/>" 
print "your mail is :", mail
print "<br/><br/>"
print "your department is :", department
print "<br/><br/>"
print "your project is :", project
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

**/server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import BaseHTTPServer 
import CGIHTTPServer 
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer 
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler 

server_address = ("", 8000) 
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"] 
httpd = server(server_address, handler) 
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: that's two new files ? I don't understand their usefulness.

Comment: In `info.py` you have to save `sys.argv` with `server software version install_path`. And in `help_get.py` you have to read file to get that values. When you `import info` then `sys.argv` are empty so `install_path` will be empty too.

Comment: so you want to import these two files inh info ? could you resume all the code of each (important) script ?

Comment: Could you add comments in new line of code in your info.py

Comment: I tested your code, but I don't understand your modification , and when I execute : ./info.py server Eclipse 7.8 C:/bla/bli/blo Linux H1054   I don't have error, but no web page opens by the webbrowser ... and you added user_os, user_login in info.py but these infos can't be recover in web application ( client-side) you know ?

Comment: When I execute : ./info.py server Eclipse 7.8 C:/bla/bli/blo Linux H1054, I have this error : (gedit:6796): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_is_ancestor: assertion `ancestor != NULL' failed

Comment: It is problem with Gedit and GTK, not with script - so off-topic. Run script directly in terminal/cmd.exe

Comment: `user_os`, `user_login` are only new names for old variables and values - they were in `/info.py` before but in `main()` - see in your code `sys.platform` and `getpass.getuser()` - and you try to get that values in `hello_get.py` as `"OS is :", os` and `'Unix user is : ', user`

Comment: your script does not even open the browser

Comment: I run this on Linux and it open browser for me - so I have no clue why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm working with debian but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: You can add `print` before and after `webbrower()` to see whether it is executed. You can also print `f.name` and check (manualy) whether this file exists.

Comment: so when I execute : ./info.py server Eclipse 7.8 C:/bla/bli/blo Linux H1054 ,it opens the webbrowser but when I TYPE ON OK BUTTON, the webbrowser propose to download hello_get.py ( as yesterday ).

Comment: I did not know the extension phtml

Comment: You can use extension `.hello_world`. It doesn't matter for script. Beside Linux doesn't care about extension - you can have script without extension because Linux use first line in script  to recognise what program to use for this script (`#!/usr/bin/python`, `#!/usr/bin/perl`, etc).

Comment: Download problem - check as yesterday: Is it downloaded from `http://localhost/.../` ? , What you have in downloaded file ? Is there error message in console with `BaseHTTPServer` ?

Comment: I run `info.py` in folder `cgi/` If you run it in other folder then you will have to change path in `open("config.txt", "w")` in `info.py`. `config.txt` have to be written in folder `cgi` because `hello_py` is looking for `config.txt` in folder `cgi`.

Comment: Can you comment your code especially with that : in info.py : def main( server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path, user_os, user_login) -> Why are your defined user_os and user_login in the def ? Because with that we have to execute 6 parameters in command line and I have to execute only 4.  I don't understand this line in info.py again :                       contenu = string.Template(template).substitute                    sys.argv.append(user_os)                                  config_file = open("config.txt", "w")-> Why open new file ?
json.dump(sys.argv, config_file)

Comment: When I type in OK, I have install path, os, IP, Unix user, name, mail, department, projetct but not the name of the application we have in previous page.

Comment: so I added the name of the application with my_argv[2) in hello_get.py, but I thought to display this parameter, we add to put : sys.argv[num of parameter].

Comment: I saw a BIG problem, when we execute ./scriptInfo.py server Eclipse 7.8 C:/bla/bli/blo Linux H1054, the first page display these parameters ( we have Linux and H1054 as user_OS and user_login), but the first page display linux2 as os and H1057 as user ( that's data calculated) and when I type on OK I see : os = Linux and user = H1054 ( that's data from command line), are you understand ?

Comment: I corrected and removed user_os and user_name as parameters in command line , I get them directly from the OS.